# Problem with encoding running Python file on flask in Apache

Tags: python, flask

Using Flask on apache webserver on CentOS (ClearOS).

Running an APP FLASK web project and in that file I want to run another python file with command: os.system("python3 module.py") which becomes a problem because it returns encoding ANSI_X3.4-1968.

In my app I would like to run the file as a cron so I will just open the file and run as below.

```
    @app.route('/crontab')
    def do_crontab():
        crontab_arg = request.args.get('cron')
        app_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        crontab_run = "python3 " + app_root + "/module.py " + crontab_arg
        os.system(crontab_run)
        return "Done"
```

At my local environment with Flask this works and returns utf-8.

In the file "module.py" I use command: sys.stdout.encoding and that is what's giving me the results.

I'm using the same python3.8 and same env. So the difference is different OS and Apache instead of Werkzeug.

On my server:

```
    [root@server ~]# locale
    LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
    LC_CTYPE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_PAPER="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_NAME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_ADDRESS="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_TELEPHONE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="sv_SE.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=sv_SE.UTF-8
```

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Can you share your Apache config? I guess you're using mod_wsgi? Have you edited `/etc/apache2/envvars` at all?

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.

1. http://lyron.gyllenwaldt.com/httpd.conf (apache config file)
2. Using mod_wsgi

I haven't edited any envvars.... using ClearOS (built on CentOS).

More or less followed the guide: https://dev.to/sm0ke/flask-deploy-with-apache-on-centos-minimal-setup-2kb7

Comment: Ah, Apache doesn't necessarily use the system locale by default. Try uncommenting the last line in `/etc/apache2/envvars` and restarting Apache.

Comment: That did the trick :) Many thanks! =)

Comment: Great, I’ll add that as an answer 

Comment: I actually have one more encoding issue and when I have a string with swedish characters like åäö and try for example send that string to sendmail it will generate a problem at the server: UnicodeDecoreError: ascii codec can't decode.

In the beginning of the python file I have.
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-

It works if I run the python file from terminal but not via Apache/FLASK.

Answer (score 0):

Apache doesn't necessarily use the system locale by default.

Try uncommenting the last line in /etc/apache2/envvars and restarting Apache. This will make Apache use your system locale.